Kivy UI not updating correctly on first interaction with CustomSpinnerButton
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.core.window import Window

class GridDropDown(ModalView):
    def __init__(self, button_ref, options, \*\*kwargs):
    super(GridDropDown, self).__init__(\*\*kwargs)
    self.size_hint = (None, None)
    self.width = Window.width \* 0.6
    self.auto_dismiss = False

    self.button_ref = button_ref

    grid_layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=5, size_hint_y=None)
    grid_layout.bind(minimum_height=grid_layout.setter('height'))

    scroll_view = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(self.width, Window.height * 0.5))
    scroll_view.do_scroll_x = False

    for option in options:
        btn = Button(text=option, size_hint_y=None, height=40, size_hint_x=1)
        btn.bind(on_release=self.on_select)
        grid_layout.add_widget(btn)

    scroll_view.add_widget(grid_layout)
    self.add_widget(scroll_view)

def on_select(self, instance):
    self.button_ref.text = instance.text
    self.dismiss()

class CustomSpinnerButton(Button):
options = ListProperty(\[\])
text = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomSpinnerButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(on_release=self.open_dropdown)

    def open_dropdown(self, *args):
        dropdown = GridDropDown(button_ref=self, options=self.options)
        dropdown.open()

    def on_option_select(self, value):
            self.text = value

class MainScreen(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, \*\*kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(\*\*kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        self.padding = 5
        self.spacing = 10

        self.name_button = CustomSpinnerButton(text='Name', font_size='20sp', options=["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"])
        self.add_widget(self.name_button)
        self.profession_button = CustomSpinnerButton(text='Profession', font_size='20sp', options=["Engineer", "Doctor", "Artist"])
        self.add_widget(self.profession_button)

        self.name_button.bind(on_release=self.on_name_selected)

    def on_name_selected(self, instance):
        name_to_profession = {
        'Alice': 'Engineer', 'Bob': 'Doctor', 'Charlie': 'Artist'
    }
    profession = name_to_profession.get(instance.text, '')
    if profession:
        self.profession_button.text = profession

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()`

I am working on an application using Kivy, where I have two dropdown-style buttons, one named "Name" and another "Profession". Each time a name is selected, the corresponding profession should automatically be selected in the "Profession" button. However, I am encountering a problem: upon selecting a name for the first time, the "Profession" button does not update with the corresponding profession. The update only occurs on the second click on the same name. This suggests there is an issue with the UI update method that only takes effect after the second click. I have tried several approaches to solve this problem, including changes in how events are handled and UI updates, but none have effectively resolved the issue. I need help understanding why this occurs and how I can solve it so that the profession is correctly updated on the first click.

You are binding to the wrong Button. The line:
self.name_button.bind(on_release=self.on_name_selected)

triggers the on_name_selected() method when the main Spinner Button is released. This happens before the name is actually selected. You need to call on_name_selected() when the name option Button is released. Try modifying the on_select() method of GridDropDown like this:
def on_select(self, instance):
    self.button_ref.text = instance.text
    # call the method to update the profession
    App.get_running_app().root.on_name_selected(instance)
    self.dismiss()

